# Load MySQL data into texboxes on button click

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have a webpage that needs to load data from a MySQL db into textboxes. So, the textboxes already exist and the values needs to be updated with those from the db. I have a JavaScript function for the button click, a PHP script to connect the db, but it doesn't seems to work. It just copies  in the textboxes, but the value stored in the db.
Any idea what I do wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
   <title></title>
   <style type="text/css">
        ...
   </style>
   <script>
   //LOAD DATA      
        function btn_load_Click(){
                document.getElementById('item1').value ="<?php echo $row['item1'];?>" ;
                document.getElementById('item2').value ="<?php echo $row['item2'];?>" ;
                document.getElementById('item3').value ="<?php echo $row['item3'];?>" ;
                document.getElementById('item4').value ="<?php echo $row['item4'];?>" ;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<?php
$servername = "something.com.mysql";
$username = "myName";
$password = "xxxx";
$dbname = "myDB"

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if (!$conn){
die("Connection failed:".mysqli_connect_error());
}
else {
$sql = "SELECT item1, item2, item3, item4 FROM myTable";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

}
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
<form id="form1" style="width:500px;" method="post">
    <div><button type="button" id="btn_load" onClick="btn_load_Click();" ></button></div>
<div id="MyItems">
    <div><input id="item1" type="text" value=""/></div>
    <div><input id="item2" type="text" value=""/></div>
    <div><input id="item3" type="text" value=""/></div>
    <div><input id="item4" type="text" value=""/></div>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you should use `ajax`.

Comment: Move your database query to somewhere before the `$row` data is used.

Comment: php is a server side scripting language.. which executed only in your server. And javascript executed on your browser... first understand the difference hen you can get the solution..

Comment: `mysql_` is deprecated. Use `mysqli` everywhere if you chose so. `$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);`

Comment: Is your `myTable` only has one row? Then fetch the four columns and assign it to each textbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first.

- Don't mix `mysql_*` API with `mysqli_*`. This will give error and problems.
- Better if you could use prepared statement, as `mysql_*` is already deprecated.
- PHP and Javascript is different with one another. You can't just assign a PHP value to Javascript variable.

I'll teach you step by step on how to achieve your goals using [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/).

First, you have to download jQuery [here](http://jquery.com/download/).

The trick we can do is to hide the row we have fetched from your query using hidden inputs. You are also mixing `mysqli_*` API with `mysql_*`, so this is wrong. I'll also introduce to you [prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php).

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

/* START PREPARING YOUR QUERY */
if($stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT item1, item2, item3, item4 FROM myTable")){
  $stmt->execute(); /* EXECUTE THE QUERY */
  $stmt->bind_result($item1, $item2, $item3, $item4); /* STORE THE RESULT TO THESE VARIABLES */
  $stmt->fetch(); /* FETCH THE RESULTS */
  $stmt->close(); /* CLOSE THE PREPARED STATEMENT */
}
```

Then we can store the fetched data to these hidden inputs.

```
<input type="hidden" id="hid-item1" value="<?php echo $item1; ?>">
<input type="hidden" id="hid-item2" value="<?php echo $item1; ?>">
<input type="hidden" id="hid-item3" value="<?php echo $item1; ?>">
<input type="hidden" id="hid-item4" value="<?php echo $item1; ?>">
```

After that, we can now create a script, which will get the values from our hidden inputs and put it in your textboxes when the button is clicked.

```
<script src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script> <!-- REPLACE NECESSARY FILE DEPENDING ON THE VERSION YOU HAVE DOWNLOADED -->
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function(){ /* PREPARE YOUR SCRIPT */
    $("#btn_load").click(function(){ /* WHEN THE BUTTON IS CLICKED */

      /* GET THE VALUES OF THE HIDDEN INPUTS */
      var hiditem1 = $("#hid-item1").val();
      var hiditem2 = $("#hid-item2").val();
      var hiditem3 = $("#hid-item3").val();
      var hiditem4 = $("#hid-item4").val();

      /* THEN PUT THEM INTO THE DESIGNATED TEXTBOXES */
      $("#item1").val(hiditem1);
      $("#item2").val(hiditem2);
      $("#item3").val(hiditem3);
      $("#item4").val(hiditem4);

    });
  });

</script>
```

You can also take a look at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Logan_Wayne/2hrze116/) for an example.